# Template ViewModel's SelectList property magically selected when rendered in view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have a master-detail view that allow users to dynamically add child records through jQuery DOM manipulation0, and then posting the whole master-detail form back to my `HttpPost` `Edit` method. My master view model is like this:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    // Other properties skipped for brevity
    public ICollection<BarViewModel> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

My child view model:

```
public class BarViewModel
{
    public int BazId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BazSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Edit` action, I populate my view model through Entity Framework and Automapper:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // Fetch from db through Entity Framework, 
        // project to view model through AutoMapper
        var viewModel = FooRepository.GetById(id)
                                     .Project()
                                     .To<FooViewModel>()
                                     .Single();


        // Populate ViewBag with an empty template BarViewModel to be manipulated
        // through jQuery
        ViewBag.BarTemplateViewModel = new BarViewModel
        { 
            BazSelectList = FooRepository.GetBazSelectList() 
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FooViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Skipped for brevity
    }
}
```

From the debugger, I made sure all `SelectListItem` in `BazSelectList` had the `Selected` property value of `false` when a GET request is triggered to my `Edit` action method. Then my view is rendered:

```
@model FooViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @*Other properties skipped for brevity*@

    @*Model binding magic here, editor template rendered for each BarViewModel*@
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bars)

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add Bar</button>
}

@* BarViewModel template here *@
@Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/BarViewModel",
              (BarViewModel)ViewBag.BarTemplateViewModel)
```

My `BarViewModel` editor template:

```
@model BarViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BazId, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BazId, 
                              Model.BazSelectList,
                              string.Empty,
                              new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When the view renders, `ViewBag.BarTemplateViewModel.BazSelectList` has one of the `SelectListItem` selected when it shouldn't, since I am passing an empty `BarViewModel` instance to the `ViewBag`. This is confirmed since I can see `BazSelectList` being pre-selected when I clicked the "Add Bar" button. The expected behaviour is to have a non-selected dropdown list. Can anyone help?

Comment: You haven't included enough code to understand. Where and how are you generating the dropdown and what is `GetBazSelectList()`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I think it's not related to the `GetBazSelectList` method, since the debugger showed that none of the `SelectListItem`s were selected when a breakpoint is set in the controller...However one of the option was selected when I set a breakpoint inside the `Edit` view

Comment: Are you using a strongly typed helper? Does the value of the property you binding to match the value of one of the `SelectListItem`? Why do you think _the expected behaviour is to have a non-selected dropdown list_? Have you used the overload that accepts the `option label`?

Comment: I expect the drop down list for my **template** to be non-selected because I passed an empty view model to the `ViewBag`. But of course I expected `FooViewModel.Bars` should have their drop down lists populated with their selected values accordingly

Comment: Are you sure none of the options generated by `GetBazSelectList` have a value of `0`? Tested with your code (just the `Html.Partial()` and some dummy values for `BazSelectList`) If none of the `SelectListItems` have `Value="0"` then the "empty" option is selected.

Comment: Yes I am quite sure, however I did found a workaround. Posting it soon as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution. Wrapping the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to a call to the `SelectList` constructor solved my problem, i.e. changing this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BazId, 
                      Model.BazSelectList,
                      string.Empty,
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BazId, 
                      new SelectList(Model.BazSelectList, "Value", "Text"), 
                      string.Empty,
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```